# Copy and Rename troubles with PHP

Tags: php, html

I have this code to copy an html file and rename it. However it doesn't do this, and I have tried tons of variations of the code but still nothing. I'm probably just overlooking something, or I forgot something.

```
$file = 'example.html';
$newfile = '$bla.html;
```

Any ideas on how to fix this? Or a different code? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I hope you have more code than *just* that...

Comment: Also $'s inside of single quotes are taken literally. You need double quotes for those to be parsed as a variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you're doing here is creating variables, you have to *actually* copy the file. Check out PHP's `copy()` function.

Here's an example of how to use it:

```
$file = 'example.txt'; //path to source file, not just the filename
$newfile = 'example.txt.bak'; //same for this string as above

if (!copy($file, $newfile)) {
    echo "failed to copy $file...\n";
}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php

Answer (score -3):

Alternatively you can do

```
`$file = 'example.html';
$newfile = 'bla.html;
file_get_contents($file);
file_put_contents($file,$newfile);`
```

Comment: This code doesn't do anything AND would be a waste of resources even if you did it correctly.